# How do I make two required_if validation for my request? Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to make `responses.*.answer_id` required if `responses.*.questiontype == radio` or `checkbox` and `responses.*.required == 1`

But when I make it like this it is not working:

```
$data = request()->validate([
    'responses.*.answer_id' => 'required_if:responses.*.questiontype,radio,|required_if:responses.*.required, 1',
    'responses.*.answer_id.*' =>'required_if:responses.*.questiontype,checkbox,|required_if:responses.*.required, 1',
```

This is what I have in my view:

```
@if($question->questiontype === 'radio')
    <div class="card-body">
        @error('responses.'. $key . '.answer_id')
            <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
        @enderror

        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
            <label for="answer{{ $answer->id }}">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <input type="radio" name="responses[{{ $key }}][answer_id]" id="answer{{ $answer->id }}" 
                    {{ (old('responses.' . $key . '.answer_id')== $answer->id) ? 'checked' : ''}}
                    class="mr-2" value="{{ $answer->id }}">
                    {{ $answer->answer }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][question_id]" value="{{ $question->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][questiontype]" value="{{ $question->questiontype }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][required]" value="{{ $question->required }}">
                </li>
            </label>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>

@elseif($question->questiontype === 'text')
    <div class="card-body">
        @error('responses.'. $key . '.answer_text')
            <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
        @enderror
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="text" name="responses[{{ $key }}][answer_text]">
            <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][question_id]" value="{{ $question->id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][questiontype]" value="{{ $question->questiontype }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][required]" value="{{ $question->required }}">
        <label for="responses[{{ $key }}][answer_text]">Provide answer</label>
        </div>
    </div>

@elseif($question->questiontype === 'textarea')
    <div class="card-body">
        @error('responses.'. $key . '.answer_text')
            <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
        @enderror
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <textarea name="responses[{{ $key }}][answer_text]"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][question_id]" value="{{ $question->id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][questiontype]" value="{{ $question->questiontype }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][required]" value="{{ $question->required }}">
           <label for="responses[{{ $key }}][answer_text]">Provide answer</label>
        </div>
    </div>

@elseif($question->questiontype === 'checkbox')
    <div class="card-body">
        @error('responses.'. $key . '.answer_id')
            <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
        @enderror
        <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
        <label for="answer{{ $answer->id }}">
            <li class="list-group-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="responses[{{ $key }}][answer_id][]" id="answer{{ $answer->id }}" 
            {{ (old('responses.' . $key . '.answer_id')== $answer->id) ? 'checked' : ''}}
            class="mr-2" value="{{ $answer->id }}">
            {{ $answer->answer }}
            <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][question_id]" value="{{ $question->id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][questiontype]" value="{{ $question->questiontype }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="responses[{{ $key }}][required]" value="{{ $question->required }}">
            </li>
        </label>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif      
</div>
@endforeach
```

I would like to require the `answer_id` for radio and checkbox `questiontypes` and if the required hidden field is equal to 1.

Comment: You can try it with a custom validation [using Rule  closure method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if)

Comment: Using Rule in laravel we can have something of this nature `'responses.*.answer_id' => Rule::requiredIf(strtolower($request->questiontype) == 'radio' || strtolower($request->questiontype) == 'checkbox' && $request->required == 1 ),`